# Create docker image for nginx, php 7, mysql and magento2

Tags: magento2, database, nginx, php-7, docker

I want to create a docker image which has nginx, php7 (and required modules), mysql and magento2. Also, want to create docker-compose scripts.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to manage this Image ? I want to create a same Image and I am beginner in docker so . Any hint for me ? how to create it from scratch ? @SK

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/mageinferno/magento2-docker-compose as a prototype and then improve it for your needs.

Comment: I want to create a same Image and I am beginner in docker so . Any hint for me ? how to create it from scratch ? @KAndy

Answer (score 0):

You can use this image from Docker Hub https://hub.docker.com/r/folio3ecommerce/magento-php-apache

There are available tags for `2.4.3-p1, 2.4.4-p2, 2.4.5`

Sample **docker-compose.yml** file

```
version: '3'

services:
  magento:
    image: folio3ecommerce/magento-php-apache:2.4.5
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "${APP_PORT}:80"
    env_file: env/phpfpm.env
    links:
      - db
      - redis
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - customNetwork
    
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.4
    restart: on-failure
    command: --max_allowed_packet=256M
    ports:
      - "${DB_PORT}:3306"
    env_file: env/db.env
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - customNetwork

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0-alpine
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
    networks:
      - customNetwork

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.16.2
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "${ES_PORT}:9200"
      - "${ES_SSL_PORT}:9300"
    volumes:
      - elasticsearchdata:/var/lib/elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      ## Set custom heap size to avoid memory errors
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      ## Avoid test failures due to small disks
      ## More info at https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/issues/488
      - "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false"
      - "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete"
    networks:
      - customNetwork

volumes:
  dbdata:
  redisdata:
  elasticsearchdata:

networks:
  customNetwork:
```

Further instructions are already available on docker hub